# Expose div as property

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how I can expose a div in my .ascx that has a runat="server" and id through a property in my code-behind so that I can manipulate it through whatever .aspx page is utilizing my control.  I wasn't sure what type to use for the property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can see your `<div id="mydiv" runat="server" />` in your ascx's code behind? What type does it have there?

TYpically, those things would be surfaced as `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.GenericHtmlControl` in your code.